# cookies aren't being set by setcookie but there are 0 errors (SSO)

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am letting setcookie and parameters in the URL bar do the SSO work for me. When I login, it doesn't set the cookie. Here's an example and code.

```
<?php

$site = $_GET["source"];

$allowed_sites = array("site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com");

$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
$encodeduser = base64_encode($_SESSION["username"]);
if(in_array($site, $allowed_sites)) {
setcookie('username', $encodeduser, time() + 3600, '/', $site);
} else {
setcookie('username', $encodeduser, time() + 3600, '/', 'site1.com');
}
?>
```

site url example

```
https://login.parappawithfries.com/?source=site.parappawithfries.com
```